# Storing a curve in a django model as manytomany?

Tags: django, models, relationship, curve, manytomanyfield

I have a list of products (say diodoes) which have a curve associated to them.
For example,

- Diode 1: curve 1: [(0,1),(1,3),(2,10), ...., (100,0.5)]
- Diode 2: curve 2: [(0,2),(1,4),(2.1,19), ..., (100,0)]

So for each product there is a curve (with the same x-axis values `range(1,100)`) but different y-axis values.

My question is what is the best practice to store such data (using Django + PostgreSql) given that I want to calculate things with it later in the views (say the area under the curve, or that curve times another one, etc). I will also be charting it, so the view will have to pull the values.

My first attempts have had various limitations:

- *Naive attempt 1*

  ```
   # model.py
   for i in range(101):
       name_sects = ["x", str(i+1)]
       attrs["".join(name_sects)] = models.DecimalField(_("".join([str(i+1),' A'])), max_digits=6)


   attrs['intensity'] = model.DecimalField(_('Diode Intensity'))


   Diode = type('Diode', (models.Model,), attrs)
  ```

Ok, that creates a field for each "x", x1, x2,... etc, and I can fill each "y" in the admin ... but it's not obvious how to manipulate it in the view or the template. (and a pain to fill in, obviously)

- *Naive attempt 2*

  ```
  #model.py
  class Curve(models.Model)
      x_axis = models.PositiveIntegerField( ...)
      y_axis = models.DecimalField( ...)

  class Diode(models.Model)
      name = blah, blah
      intensity = model.DecimalField(_('Diode Intensity'), blah, blah)
      characteristic_curve = model.ManyToManyField(Curve)
  ```

Is ManyToMany the way forward? Even if to each diode corresponds one single curve? (but many points, possibly two diodes sharing a same point).

Any advice, tips or links to tools for it are very appreciated.

Comment: Do you expect to increase the number of fields in Curve or Diode? Do you really need to query something like "Which diodes share a same point"?

Comment: I don't need to query "which diodes share the same point". I'm not sure I understand the "increase the number of fields" question.  I could add "voltage" or "certification" but that would be unrelated.  I could have a simple curve (with a few points) and maybe get one with the 100 points later from the suppliers.  That could happen.

Comment: I meant to say that it can be very wasteful if you have a lot of fields and JOIN operations between them. If you don't need that kind of flexibility, you probably don't need to use several models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to improve speed (because 100 entries for each product, it's really huge and it would be slow if you have to fetch 100 products and theirs points), I would use the pickle module and store your list of tuples in a TextField (or maybe CharField if the length of the string doesn't change).

```
>>> a = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8)]
>>> pickle.dumps(a)
'(lp0\n(I1\nI2\ntp1\na(I3\nI4\ntp2\na(I5\nI6\ntp3\na(I7\nI8\ntp4\na.'
>>> b = pickle.dumps(a)
>>> pickle.loads(b)
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

Just store b in your TextField and you can get back your list really easily.

And even better, as Robert Smith says, use http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-picklefield

Comment: Thank you.  It seems like a fast and easy solution. I can't see the PickledObjectField in the admin after introducing it, but will investigate.

Answer (score 0):

I like your second approach but just a minor suggestion.

```
class Plot(models.Model):
    x_axis = models.PositiveIntegerField( ...)
    y_axis = models.DecimalField( ...)

class Curve(models.Model)
   plots = models.ManyToManyField(Plot)

class Diode(models.Model)
    name = blah, blah
    intensity = model.DecimalField(_('Diode Intensity'), blah, blah)
    curve = models.ForeignKey(Curve)
```

Just a minor suggestion for flexibility

Comment: Sorry. N00b question.  What flexibility does this offer? What is a typical case when I would need the extra level? thanks